# Setting up a default gateway in ssh_config

Tags: ssh

I'd like to know whether there is a way to assign a default ssh gateway to a hostname such that, whenever you attempt to ssh to the hostname it uses the gateway to reach the host. Ideally this should be done in the ssh_config

e.g.:
client C attempts to reach target T by

```
ssh T
```

The only way this connection can be established is through gateway GW

```
ssh -tA GW ssh T
```

EDIT: I neglected to mention that one may have various gateways which will reach different hosts

EDIT: I tried using the ssh config:

```
Host my-target-host
ProxyCommand ssh -tA GW ssh %h
```

But then I get "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal"

EDIT: Okay so I figured it out :-)
The correct config looks like this:

```
Host my-target-host
ProxyCommand ssh my-gateway-host exec nc %h %p
```

Not entirely sure why this works though...

Comment: If you found a solution to your question, please post it as an answer and accept it as the correct solution later. Thanks :)

Comment: I would love to know why it works... How does netcat know to use my forwarded ssh-agent? What about all the particulars about the ssh protocol, how does netcat know this?

Comment: That might already be a new question. In that case, ask a new question and add a link to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some tinkering and searching, I found that this works (for reasons that are beyond me):

In your ssh_config:

```
Host my-target-host
ProxyCommand ssh my-gateway-host exec nc %h %p
```

Comment: This command causes your local SSH client to establish two SSH sessions. The first is to the gateway host where it starts netcat to serve as a dumb proxy to the target host. The second is via the netcat proxy to the target host. Because it is a proxy, your local ssh-agent (not the gateway) serves the key.